# How to get the consumer group of the single consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am playing aroung Kafka, when I use

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --topic test
```

Kafka will automatically create a consumer group. I am wondering how to get the consumer group name?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`. The following command will list you all consumer groups.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

**Note:** This will only show information about consumers that use the Java Consumer API (non-Zookeeper-based consumers).

Comment: I don't have this command, and I am using 0.8.2.1 installed using brew

Comment: Why are you using an old version? You can't use a most recent version?